# Background overlay doesn't show up in my menu elementor pro

Tags: wordpress, elementor

> I'm  use elementor pro ,Why i'm not see section of background overlay appear on menu like as other tutorial online. I'm want to create    feature loop along cilp this  [(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7QRFgw4DCo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7QRFgw4DCo) but in my menu differ as clip. who know please advice me. Thank you.[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCxEi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYIm1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you select an element (e.g. Container), and hit the "Style" tab, than you can enable classic background type, and the Background Overlay menu will appear underneath.

I found the solution in this video: https://youtu.be/w8KtcI0AWlU?t=521

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).